# Find names similar to a given name in a large data set

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

I'm trying to find a 'similar' name to every item in a list

```
 nearName[name_, namesList_] := 
   Module[{lista, pos},
     lista = EditDistance[ToLowerCase[name], ToLowerCase[ToString[#]]] & /@ (namesList);
     pos = Flatten[Position[lista, Min[lista]]];
     If[Length[pos] > 1 || Min[lista] > 3 , Missing["NotAvailable"], namesList[[pos]]]]
```

The problem is that with a very large input (`nameList` contains about 400k items and I make about 1k calls to `nearName`), `nearName` is using a lot of CPU. Is there any way I can make this faster?

Comment: I think it would certainly help if you did `ToLowerCase[ToString[#]] & /@ namesList` just once before any calls your `nearName` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd think this more efficient:

```
names = {"rob", "joe", "jack"};

find = Module[{nf = Nearest[#2], res},
              If[EditDistance[#, res = First@nf[#]] <= 3,res, Missing["NotAvailable"]]] &;

find["boc", names]
find["franny", names]

(*
"rob"
Missing["NotAvailable"]
*)
```

Do `Lowercase` conversion if case matters, and if you plan on many repeated look-ups, probably best to generate the nearest function `nf` once and re-use it.

Re-reading your OP, I think this better fits the question (based on my interpretation of the code):

```
find = Module[{nf = Nearest[#2], res},
              If[EditDistance[#, First@(res = nf[#])] <= 3 && (Length@res == 1 || 
                 EditDistance[#, res[[1]]] != EditDistance[#, res[[2]]]), 
                 First@res, Missing["NotAvailable"]]] &
```

Answer (score 3):

`EditDistance` is an expensive computation ( `O(longestStringLength + distance^2)` ), so it is helpful to do whatever you can to eliminate candidates before you use it. The idea here is to minimize the `distance^2` contribution to your overall testing time. You can start by filtering on `StringLength`, to within +/- x characters of your test string since that is implicit. If that shrinks the list sufficiently, then do your `EditDistance`, but if the list is still very large you could also do a second pass and check whether the number of mismatching `Characters` is within tolerance; this isn't free (computationally), so whether this would be worth it will depend on how much you can shave off the list with `StringLength`.  `Nearest` uses `EditDistance` for strings, so it could be used to tidy up your code a bit but it will still be slow if you run it on a very large list. However, querying with `Nearest` (as rasher noted) will be faster than applying `EditDistance` to the whole list first. `EditDistance` also has an `IgnoreCase` option which is cheaper than making separate calls to `ToLowerCase`, but in any case `ToLowerCase` is `Listable` so you should take advantage of that if you use it.